# Visualizing N-dimensions on a graph

Tags: cluster-analysis, dimension

I have been conducting my thesis lately, and in the first stage I do some form of clustering in order to generate `K` user-specified clusters. 
The size of the input matrix that I cluster is `N*M`. Where N is the population and M are the samples.

After the clustering is done, I would have loved to see how those clusters look on the field. But I can't picture anything more than 3 dimensions.

Is there a way to visualize M dimensions? Using R? Java? Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, plenty. Do some research for your thesis.

- PCA
- MDS
- Parallel coordinates
- tSNE
- ISOMAP
- locally linear embeddings
- Fisher LDA
- LMNN